# RAND in T-sql function

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Can  any one  tell why t-sql  not allowing using RAND function in side a function

```
SELECT  CAST (RAND() * 10000000 as varchar(20))
```

the error is

```
Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'rand' within a function.
```

Comment: Have a look at [Creating Nondeterministic functions in SQL Server using RAND()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531450/creating-nondeterministic-functions-in-sql-server-using-rand)

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?  It works just fine on my SQL Server 2008 R2 instance.

Comment: we use mssql 2008  enterprise edition

Comment: can you post the whole function?

Comment: I'm not sure what Denny was trying; I get the same error on my 2008 R2 instance when putting that code in a function definition.

Answer (score 1):

I found this at http://zarez.net/?p=2192 (author not immediately evident) - how to cheat around this.  RAND() may count as "a side-effecting operator" because it updates the seed-number that the RAND() function uses, ready to produce the next "random" number.  Here's the cheat:

```
CREATE VIEW Get_RAND
AS
SELECT RAND() AS MyRAND
GO
```

You can read a value from a view like that in a function, but maybe there's some deep reason not to... or on the other hand, maybe it was forbidden in the first place without a good reason?